# Blazor javascript doesn't work with foreach loop of repository

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server project that is ServerPrerendered.

I use the Flickity library for generating carousels in my site.

This is the implemeentation in the _Host.chtml

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flickity.css">
    <link href="css/Carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.initF = () => {
            $('.main-carousel').flickity({
                // options
                cellAlign: 'left',
                contain: true,
                draggable: true,
                pageDots: false
            });
        }
    </script>
```

In my razor component I'm successful rendering the Flickity carousel when I'm using this setup:

```
@if (carouselItems is not null)
    {
        <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity>
           
            @foreach (var item in carouselItems)
            {
                <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="@item" /></div>
            }
        </div>
    }
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await js.InvokeAsync<object>("initF");
            }



List<string> carouselItems = new();
 protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            carouselItems = new List<string>()
            {
                "https://picsum.photos/720/540/?image=517",
                "https://picsum.photos/540/720/?image=696",
                "https://picsum.photos/720/540/?image=56",
                "https://picsum.photos/800/500/?image=1084",
                "https://picsum.photos/720/540/?image=1080",
                "https://picsum.photos/640/640/?image=1074",
                "https://picsum.photos/720/540/?image=1069"
            };

        }
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image]
[image]

But if I change it do dynamic data like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {

            widget = await _repoWidget.GetPageWidgetById(EndPoints.WidgetEndpoint + $"GetByPageWidgetId/{Id}");
            if (widget != null)
            {
                videos = await _repoArchive.Get(EndPoints.ArchiveEndpoint + $"&channelId={widget.ListId}&count={widget.Quantity}");

                

            }
        }
```

And then render the html like this:

```
@if (videos is not null)
{
    <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity>
        @foreach (var item in videos)
        {
            <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="@item.poster_image_16x9_640w" /></div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

I get this result:
[image]
[image]

It seems that the javascript is not able to "connect" to the DOM elements when I loop through the posts retrieved from the api for some reason.

I also tried to make the api call in OnAfterRenderAsync, after I invoked the IJSInterop, but with the same result.

How can I get this to work and in what do I error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are using OnInitialized and in the second you are using OnInitializedAsyc. In the second case Blazor completes its render cycle and then re renders after OnInitializedAsync returns. However, by then the "firstRender" condition is no longer true and the call to your JavaScript is not made.
To fix this, update your
`OnInitializedAsyc` to:

```
@code
{
   bool fetchComplete;
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            fetchComplete= false;
            widget = await _repoWidget.GetPageWidgetById(EndPoints.WidgetEndpoint + $"GetByPageWidgetId/{Id}");
            if (widget != null)
            {
                videos = await _repoArchive.Get(EndPoints.ArchiveEndpoint + $"&channelId={widget.ListId}&count={widget.Quantity}");

                

            }
           fetchComplete= true;
        }


}
```

And then
`OnAfterRenderAsync` as

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
                if (fetchComplete)
                {
                    fetchComplete = false;
                    await js.InvokeAsync<object>("initF");
                   
                }
}
```

I don't have access to what you are using, but this should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. I suspected that but was not sure on how to solve it. Thanks!!!